# How to convert BufferedImage to Image with 3 colors?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

There are two types of ByfferedImage:
BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY
BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY

BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY contains a lot of shades.
BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY contains only 2 colors: black and white.

I need type of BufferedImage.TYPE or solution that support 3 colors: black, white, and gray.
I need to create indexed image with 3 colors.

Who to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
byte MAX = (byte) 255;
byte[] r = new byte[] {MAX, 127, 0};
byte[] g = new byte[] {MAX, 127, 0};
byte[] b = new byte[] {MAX, 127, 0};

IndexColorModel indexColorModel = new IndexColorModel(2, 3, r, g, b); 
//6 -> bits per pixel, 3 -> size of the color arrays

BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(width, height, 
    BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED, indexColorModel);
```

Comment: Not work good. It create grayscale image. Not indexed image that contains 3 colors.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's creating a indexed image with 3 colors (white (MAX, MAX, MAX), gray (127, 127, 127) and black (0, 0, 0)). To set a pixel of a certain color, you can use setRGB, and BufferedImage will pick the closest color in the palette.

Comment: @Emd4600 Note that you only need 2 bits per pixel for >= 4 colors. No reason to waste the last 4 bits. ;-)

Comment: Oh, true. I was thinking about color combinations there. Edited, thanks :)